# How to handling SIGINT (Ctrl+C) while using PDCurses in Windows

Tags: c, sigint, pdcurses

I am using [PDCurses](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses) to write console app in Windows. I want the app to terminate when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

My minimal reproducible code is as below. If I comment out `initscr()` and `endwin()`, the app will terminal after receive `SIGINT` and print "End" in the console. However, it does not work with the two lines, and it will fun forever.

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handle_sig(int sig) {
    if (sig == SIGINT) {
        endwin();
        printf("End\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, handle_sig);
    initscr();
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does PDCurses' documentation say about signals?

Comment: @thebusybee The only description I found in the [manual](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/master/docs/MANUAL.md) was raw/noraw mode. However, even when I used `noraw()`, I still could not break it by Ctrl+C.

Comment: But then your application will receive that character, wont it? So it can react on it in a safe way. Because I'm not sure that you can call `endwin()` in a signal handler... as `printf()` is commonly a no-no in a signal handler. But I just wanted to give you a hint, I have no personal deeper experience with ncurses, let alone PDCurses. -- Did you look for examples using PDCurses that realize such functionality? There a several demos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `noraw()` mode was never really implemented for the Windows console port of PDCurses. (It is in DOS and OS/2.) I was able to correct this, although a complete fix will require a bit more work.

In the meantime, I suggest rewriting your program to handle Ctrl+C itself, if at all possible. Note that, even if noraw mode is fixed for wincon, it will probably never work in the PDCurses ports that don't depend on a controlling terminal.

But if you want to patch your PDCurses:

```
diff --git a/wincon/pdckbd.c b/wincon/pdckbd.c
index d2c3ab69..9bfc8927 100644
--- a/wincon/pdckbd.c
+++ b/wincon/pdckbd.c
@@ -215,7 +215,13 @@ static KPTAB ext_kptab[] =
 
 void PDC_set_keyboard_binary(bool on)
 {
+    DWORD mode;
+
     PDC_LOG(("PDC_set_keyboard_binary() - called\n"));
+
+    GetConsoleMode(pdc_con_in, &mode);
+    SetConsoleMode(pdc_con_in, !on ? (mode | ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT) :
+                                    (mode & ~ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT));
 }
 
 /* check if a key or mouse event is waiting */
@@ -640,8 +646,8 @@ int PDC_mouse_set(void)
        If turning off the mouse: Set QuickEdit Mode to the status it
        had on startup, and clear all other flags */
 
-    SetConsoleMode(pdc_con_in, SP->_trap_mbe ?
-                   (ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT|0x0088) : (pdc_quick_edit|0x0088));
+    //SetConsoleMode(pdc_con_in, SP->_trap_mbe ?
+    //               (ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT|0x0088) : (pdc_quick_edit|0x0088));
 
     memset(&old_mouse_status, 0, sizeof(old_mouse_status));
```

(This disables the mouse input toggle -- a quick and dirty patch.)